# Display a struct vector values based on 1 type

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm currently trying to display the total no. of topicids and testids based on the name.
However I'm having trouble doing that display. I initially had a vector containing all the data.
For e.g.
user1:name:topic1:test1
user1:name:topic2:test1
user2:name:topic1:test1
user2:name:topic2:test1

Due to the multiple duplicates in the vector, I want to display in the following format:
**username:name:numofTopics:numofTests**
user1:name:2:2
user1:name:2:2

Therefore, i thought of comparing the name against the next name in the vector and push in the element to a new vector called singleAcc. The purpose of this is to display the duplicate element as **ONE** element.

Below is my code for displaying the data

```
        vector<AccDetails> singleAcc;
        for (vector<AccDetails>::iterator itr=accInfo.begin();itr!=accInfo.end()-1; ++itr) {
            if (itr->name == itr[1].name) {
                //cout << (*itr) << endl;
                singleAcc.push_back(*itr);
            }
        }

        for (vector<AccDetails>::iterator itr = singleAcc();itr!=singleAcc();++itr) {
            cout << left
                    << setfill(' ')
                    << setw(20) << itr[0].username
                    << setw(20) << itr[0].name
                    << setw(20) << countTopics(itr->name)
                    << setw(20) << countTests()
                    << endl;            
        }
```

Problem:
On the first vector iteration, the name will not compare against the last element bcoz of `accDetails.end()-1`.
How to display the duplicate elements as **ONE** element? Is what I'm doing in the 2nd iteration the right thing?

Hope someone can help me with this. Or is there a better way to doing this?
 Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to display the numbers based on *name*? Or do you mean *username*? It seems different users can have the same name.

Comment: @snipes83 The name will be the same for user1 but it will not be the same for user2. meaning that user1 can have name john and user2 can have name mary

Answer (score 1):

### Why this won't work

Your proposed solution simply won't work as intended. Consider three elements that are considered duplicates in consecutive subsequence (I am using numbers to simplify the concept):

> [1,1,1]

- The iterator will first compare `1` to `1`, and then `push_back` the first one.
- Then it will compare *second* `1` to the third one, which again returns true, and the result that was supposed to have no duplicates ends up:

> [1,1]

So it's clearly not something you want to do. In general, it looks like a rather weird problem, but so solve this one part you've posted here, I suggest using `std::multiset`.

### A better solution

Create a comparator that tests for the `name` field just like you do here.

Then, recovering unique fields is rather simple:

```
std::multiset<AccDetail> s;
for (auto element_it = s.begin(); element_it != s.end(); element_it = s.upper_bound(*element_it)) {
    auto er = s.equal_range(*element_it);

    // use this to get all the elements with given name
    for (auto i = er.first; i != er.second; ++i)
        cout << *i << " ";

    // use this to get the number of them
    cout << std::distance(er.first, er.second);
}
```

See [**a working sample**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3b9ac370f1a02017fd46818ea6c53188-862de6335e18fd7902bf2c42ffee0752) on Coliru.

### Bonus

You are right that the iterator in first loop would go over the bounds. The solution for that is rather simple: *zip iterator* which can handle this automatically.

```
for (auto elem_pair : zip(v, v | drop(1)))
    if (elem_pair.first == elem_pair.second)
        ...
```

Boost.Range has tools that allow that code to work. It would still suffer from the problems I've mentioned, though.